# Derogatory slang in answers

Tags: discussion

There's been a little edit war in this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/29684/2100) whether or not to use the term "[douchebag](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=douchebag&defid=5268202)" as defined [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=douchebag&defid=5268202).

If slang is allowed (and I believe it is), then this insulting term should be fine.  If it it not, then where do we draw the line?

...

Comment: [What's the view on profanity?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3573/2100)

Comment: Urban Dictionary is an unreliable reference and only ever useful for its vague overview, if even that. I think it may have been misleading here, making it seem more neutral than it actually is.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You're raising an excellent point but not providing alternatives. What would be a more neutral reference source specifically for slang terms that would be more beneficial to the discussion at hand?

Comment: [A dictionary!](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/douchebag): _Also called douche. Slang: Vulgar. a contemptible or despicable person._

Comment: @Dyndrilliac We don't really need an alternative source, since the community doesn't need to consult a dictionary before deciding that a bit of language doesn't meet the standard already set; an accurate dictionary might just be useful to explain the community's decision after the fact. The point I meant to make is more that, as misleading reference, we can put some of the blame on Urban Dictionary retroactively, rather than on members. :) (If we did want a source, Doppelgreener's is better, especially with the explicit “vulgar” usage note.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My view is that if there is a reasonably polite way of saying something, then that's the way it should be said. It is hardly ever necessary to use derogatory terms, and I feel that it lowers the tone of the site as a whole and can given the wrong impression. Allowing these types of terms also then sets an example and encourages further use.

Comment: This gets to the heart of the matter: There is almost always a less offensive but equally effective alternative to using derogatory terms, and more people are likely to find content useful if it's less offensive.

Comment: @GMJoe: You can be very offensive without using swear words... ^_~

Comment: @Sardathrion Fair point; I should have said "There is almost always a less offensive but equally effective alternative to being offensive, and more people are likely to find content useful if it's less offensive." That sounds a little silly, though.

Comment: @GMJoe: I was being slightly factitious... ^_~

Comment: Yes, you can also violate Be Nice! without using swear words. Using them, however, means its pretty likely you're violating it.

Answer (score 6):

This is a pure duplicate of [Is profanity allowed on RPG.SE?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3573/2100) and in general violates the "Be Nice" overarching rule of the Stack. The post in question currently states:

"Or to use slang terms, a douchebag, or a jerk, or an asshole... Take your pick of insulting term, which of course are gender/sex/racial non-specific."

Two of those terms are clearly inappropriate in a professional environment.  They will be edited out and further use may result in behavioral warnings.

We have more than enough trouble with arguments and people baiting each other on this site without allowing curses or intensifiers.  Keep it professional and family appropriate and we can more easily maintain a civil atmosphere.