# Can I use a bleeped-out-swear if that's the name of the article I'm referencing?

Tags: discussion, policy

I know there's a pretty strict policy on swear words on this site. I just wrote an answer referencing an article by The Angry Gm, the title of which is [How to Build F$&%ing Awesome Encounters!](http://theangrygm.com/how-to-build-awesome-encounters/)

I cited it pretty much exactly like that ^ in my answer. Is it okay to use a swear word like that given that it's the title of the article? I can edit it out if the consensus is that I shouldn't name it.

Comment: A few related posts from other SE sites about a profanely-named language: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainf-ck-offensive, https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/should-we-censor-language-names/. Of course, this community can decide upon other guidelines, but this is how other sites have handled a similar topic.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, perfectly fine.  See [Is profanity allowed on RPG.SE?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3573/is-profanity-allowed-on-rpg-se) for our guidance - you can actually use swear words if they're in the original, but it certainly doesn't hurt anything to 'bleep' them and that's appreciated.

Comment: The exceptions to the last bit about harm being rare, such as where bleeping out a particular Apocalypse World move's name would make it un-Googleable.

Comment: When editing a quote, you should at least put in some editorial marker so it's clear that the original used the full term.  There doesn't appear to be a word for that in English (it'd be like the opposite of [sic errat scriptum]), but I feel like I remember there was one and it's another latin loan or something and I just can't find it.

Comment: Also, if you post a swear and it's in the original it'd be appropriate, if worried about reactions, to put a [sic] after the swear to make it clear why it's there.  You don't actually need to on our site, but you can if you want.

Comment: You could simply put the expurgated word in brackets to indicate an editorial change: How to Build [F--ing] Awesome Encounters!